# When shouldn't you write $E(X)$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value

We observe the discrete random variable $X = (X_1, . . . , X_n)$ with state space
$S$, whose distribution we do not know but we are assuming that its joint p.m.f. belongs
to a known family {${f_θ : θ ∈ Θ}$}. We derive a sufficient statistic $T(X)$.

Explain why it is wrong to write $E[X]$ and correct it.

Hey, I am unsure on this question, as I see nothing wrong with that.

Comment: I don't see how there could be anything wrong with **writing** that, unless you're writing it as the answer to a question where it would be a wrong answer.  Of course the expected value may or may not exist.

Comment: I think that last part is the point. You can't write $\mathbb{E}[X]$ if you don't know that $X$ is integrable.

Comment: So what could you write instead @ClementC.?

Comment: ? Depends where, for what. Just, not $E[X]$. Some random variables don't have an expectation...

Comment: Sorry, I realised that I missed out the last part out of the actual question. It says to say why you cannot say $E[X]$ and to correct it.

Comment: Your question, as you just edited, does not seem to make sense. Before the "Explain why it is wrong to write $E[X]$", we don't have $E[X]$ written *anywhere*. So there is nothing to "correct." Are you missing parts of the statement? (E.g., $T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic for $\theta$? Is its definition written, maybe involving $E[X]$?)

Comment: If I had to guess, I assume it means that the notation is wrong, or that it doesn't exist etc. as the next part of the question says  Let $T(X)$ be a sufficient statistic. Is it ok to write $E[X|T(X)]$?

Comment: But no, there is no mention of the expectation before this, that is the full question @ClementC.

Comment: Are you pulling this question from a book or homework?

Comment: Homework. The answer below is correct though I believe. The notation used below does appear in classes

Comment: This is also asked at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/445812/is-it-correct-to-write-bbb-ex-or-bbb-e-thetax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I had to guess at what "Explain why" is hinting at, it's that the expectation of $X$ depends on $\theta$. You know that $X$'s distribution is one member of the family $\{f_\theta\}$, but you're not told which member. Therefore to be specific you have to write $E_\theta[X]$, i.e., the expectation of $X$ assuming $\theta$ is true, and then continue your analysis with that assumption.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is right, given the notation is similar to things used in class. This would make $E[X|T(X)]$ "right" too, as $T(X)$ doesn't depend on $θ$ as it is a sufficient statistic?

Comment: For $T(X)$ to be a sufficient statistic you need to show that the distribution of $X$ conditional on $T(X)$ is free of $\theta$. Once you've established this, then also $E_\theta [X\mid T(X)]$ will be free of $\theta$, so you could at that point drop the $\theta$ from $E_\theta$.